# Petrel, volume calculations of a part of the model

Tags: petrel

I need to calculate the volumes not of the model itself, but of a part of it.
But the calculation of all the volumes in the table for some reason equals 0.

I trim the model as follows:
[model cropping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzjcV.jpg)

Volume calculations:
[volume calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqSEJ.jpg)

output, all values is 0:
[output results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqaOf.png)

how to solve this problem?

original model:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1axbPZC62_cclQWMUJBF6Si6PVwDkTBI1/view?usp=sharing